# Is there a working real world project using Clojure that take advantage of multi-core system that I can take a look?

Tags: java, clojure

Is there a working real world project using Clojure that take advantage of multi-core system that I can take a look?

I want to if Clojure is still in a toy-language phrase or it's really "happening soon".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at the many examples posted up in the Google discussion group.  They are interesting and a couple of them non-trivial in another language.  I think those examples are more than enough proof about whether Clojure is a "toy" language or not.

The designer, Rich Hickey, uses the language himself for his work so I wouldn't be surprised if you find it very production ready.  The API at this point isn't changing much since things are headed toward a 1.0 release, so you don't really have to worry too much about hte rug being pulled out under your feet.  Probably the least stable part right now, if you're going to do your Lisping in Emacs, is SLIME and swank-clojure.  It's pretty imperative that you use latest versions of both directly from their repositories (I use the GitHub mirrors).

Get it while it's hot.

Answer (score 4):

On the Clojure group today there's a [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/85649a134cf22655?tvc=2&pli=1) about a fellow doing just that. It looks like a lot of middleware glue for a vet hospital, but unfortunately there's no data up on it (it says this will change in the next few months).

Answer (score 3):

Consider taking a look at the source code for [enclojure](http://enclojure.org/)--a Netbeans IDE for Clojure. You can browse it [here](http://code.google.com/p/enclojure-nb-clojure-plugin/source/browse/#svn/trunk) or download via svn [here](http://code.google.com/p/enclojure-nb-clojure-plugin/source/checkout). You'll find a healthy mix of Java and Clojure for the implementation. It seems to be under active development as you can see [here](http://code.google.com/p/enclojure-nb-clojure-plugin/source/list).

It appears an Eclipse nature is being developed [here](http://code.google.com/p/clojure-dev/) but from the looks of the code, it's almost entirely in Java.

Perhaps more illuminating would be looking at the source code to [Clojure](http://clojure.org/) itself. Aside from the core implementation, the bulk of the code is written in [itself](http://code.google.com/p/clojure/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/clj/clojure).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote Mire to be an example for just that kind of purpose. It's a simple app, but it involves concurrent processing and shared state. It's built in a series of small steps, each one building on the last, and each step is stored as a separate git branch, so you can follow along with the development incrementally.

http://github.com/technomancy/mire